# Use MediaWiki login on non-mediawiki pages (in the same domain?)

Tags: php, mediawiki, session-cookies

I need to use the MediaWiki login in a non-mw page (on the same domain)

I looked at the cookies, but the mw_UserName cookie remains after I logout (and the mw_Logout cookie remains after I log back in) - and I have no clue how to use mw_session cookie, but I presume that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
$preIP = dirname( __FILE__ );
require_once( "$preIP/includes/WebStart.php" );
require_once("$preIP/includes/User.php");

$t = new User();
$user = $t->newFromSession();
$user->load();
```

I looked in /includes/ and so user.php, so I tried to include that, but it gave an error. So I looked at how MediaWiki did it, and I saw that WebStart.php defined the var that User.php required.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this works, but probably mediawiki is using PHP sessions. Then you might just need to set the session name:

```
session_name('mw_session');
session_start();
echo session_id(), '<pre>', var_dump($_SESSION);
die();
```

for the first insight. (I remember for some older mediawiki versions it was using file-bases sessions).

Comment: Check that the mediawiki session is still active. And I've added the output of the session_id. it should have the same value as of the cookie. If not, it's not taken over.

Comment: I now have two mw_session cookies. Help! (Yes, the session was still active)